# Please help us diagram this trig problem.

Tags: trigonometry

We are not looking for a solution. We are confused by the wording and need help with the diagram. Then we can solve the problem on our own.

Here is the exercise in the text.

> A surveyor is measuring the length of a lake.  He takes angle measurements from two positions, $A$ and $B$, that are 136 m apart and on the same side of the lake.  From $B$, the measure of the angle between the sight lines to the ends of the lake is $130^\circ$, and the measure of the angle between the sight lines to $A$ and one end of the lake is $120^\circ$.  From $A$, the measure of the angle between the sight lines to the ends of the lake is $65^\circ$, and the measure of the angle between the sight lines to $B$ and the same end of the lake is $20^\circ$.  Calculate the length of the lake, to the nearest metre.

Here is our diagram. What angles are $120^\circ$ and $20^\circ$?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, this is _horribly_ undetermined.  I don't understand what it means to be "the end of the lake".  I can make assumptions that make this problem solvable but it would be assumptions that should be specified.  What shape are we to assume the lake takes that we can assume boundaries???

The very idea of measuring the "length" of a lake is very subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility: 
[image]
The "ends" of the lake are points $C$ and $D$; $\angle CBD=130^\circ$, $\angle DBA=120^\circ$, $\angle CAD=65^\circ$, $\angle BAD=20^\circ$.